# Python PIL save location

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Trying to save an output GIF, but despite changing the path for the save multiple times and the code running fine, no GIF files show up in my documents folder.

```py
frames[0].save('Users\\alexdhesi\\Documents\\output.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=100, loop=0)
```

Help please!!!

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose that you are on Windows. If you're not, please specify it.

Right now, you are saving somewhere that is relative to the place you are running the Python interpreter. You should be using an absolute path to be sure where you file is going to be saved. So I'm going to guess that something like that is going to work:

```py
frames[0].save(r'C:\Users\alexdhesi\Documents\output.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=100, loop=0)
```